# Addint a fullcalendar event with Bootstarp modal in Flask Python

Tags: javascript, html, forms, flask

I Can't find any code sample where I could add an event thru the eventClick: function that would pop up a bootstrap modal, and then on he submit event of that modal-form would "rip" the fields of that modal to send it to a url route in flask to add and then re render the the fullcalendar based on changes or additions.

I perfectly know how to render an event on a bootstrap modal, my issue is the ripping of whatever is put in the modal so I can pass it to the url .
Can anyone be so kind to point me into some code?

thanks so very much..

Comment: Are you wanting to send it via AJAX or a regular postback? Either way, put the fields inside a form and then you can easily either a) submit them using a normal postback or b) use `FormData` in Javascript to read the contents of the form and send that in your AJAX request.

Comment: hi ADyson, Im sending via Ajax, already found a sample thanks